# What does List[:][:] really do in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, cloning

I tried to make a copy of a 2 dimensional array using the splicing operator. Intuitivelly, it feels like if I do this:

```
L = [[5, 6], [7, 8]] 
M = L[:][:]
```

then `M` would be a cloned copy of every *nested* element in `L`. So I could change items in `M[0]` without changing `L`:

```
M[1] = [3, 4] 
M[0][1] = 2
```

But when I do this:

```
print(L)
#returns [[5,2],[7,8]]
```

What is actually going on in Python's memory when I performed the `[:][:]` operation?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list for detailed info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just makes a copy of the list on the left side of the operator `[:]`.

`[:][:]` does `copy of copy`. You can do `M = L[:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:]` and it works the same way :D

To make a copy of nested lists as well you should do it like `M = [x[:] for x in L[:]]`

Then M would be a cloned copy of every nested element in L. It is not true because `L[:][:]` is the same as `(L[:])[:]` it is a copy of the copy of the original list.

`M[1] = [3, 4]` here you modify the second item of the `COPY`.

But here `M[0][1] = 2` you are modifying an item of the original nested array since `[:]` doesn't do any copy operations on nested lists and the copied original list item was not "simple".

Comment: There's no point in slicing `L` in `M = [x[:] for x in L[:]]`. `M = [x[:] for x in L]` would make the same copy, but faster because it doesn't make an unnecessary shallow copy of `L` first.

Comment: of course not, just wanted to show some more examples for the source code block without touching it too much. Show "how it works" deeper

Answer (score 1):

**Warning!** In Python, when it's a list and doing `x = y`, changing values in `y` changes `x`.

It's not a copy by value but **copy by reference** here. E.g.

```
>>> x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> y = x
>>> y[0][1] = 5 
>>> x
[[1, 5], [3, 4]]
```

But how you're copying using `x = y[:]` is right. And the chaining of `[:]` is redundant.

First lets understand how to really "copy by value" for this nested list. To do so, in general, you can use the `copy` module.

```
>>> import copy
>>> x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> y[0][1] = 5
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> y
[[1, 5], [3, 4]]
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python , doing `y = x[:]` is the same as using copy.copy

Now going back to the `[:]` notation. If we go down the nested-ness and look at the types:

```
>>> x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(x[0])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(x[:])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(x[:][0])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(x[:][0][0])
<class 'int'>
>>> type(x[:][0][0][0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

We see that if we directly assess the values inside the inner list at some point the integer value is not a list and so we can't get an index from it.

What happens when we keep on doing `x[:][:][:][:][:]`, we see that it checks out at it's allowing us to keep on accessing the list but **are we really getting into the nested list values when we do `[:]`?**

```
>>> type(x[:][:][:])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(x[:][:][:][:][:])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(x[:][:][:][:][:][:])
<class 'list'>
```

Here we see the types are not changing, and if we look at the actual value, if we start copying it:

```
>>> x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> y
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x[:])
>>> y
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x[:][:])
>>> y
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x[:][:][:])
>>> y
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x[:][:][:][:])
>>> y
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Essentially, you are accessing the full list at the first `x[:]` and then the continuous chaining of `[:]` isn't exactly accessing/traversing the nested loop, but **just re-copying the copied list.**

Think of `z=x[:][:]` as:

```
y = x[:] 
z = y[:]
```

---

It's a good point now to read the documentations/questions on slicing

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html
- [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

To dig deeper, you'll have to go into the implementation.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/sliceobject.c